# batch files folder and text file creation

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch files and i want to create a batch file that will

1. create a folder on the desktop
2. then add a text file to that folder
3. and then move the folder to another folder on the desktop

Here is what i have so far:

```
ECHO off
ECHO CREATING NEW DIRECTORY AND FILE....
md "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\System software"
echo.>"C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\systemsoftware.txt"
MOVE  "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\System software" "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\desktop\systemsoftware.txt"
ECHO Complete
PAUSE
```

This creates two folders but places both on the desktop and not in a single folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the required behaviour you described the following will do:

```
ECHO off
ECHO CREATING NEW DIRECTORY AND FILE....
md "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\System software"
echo.>"C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\System software\systemsoftware.txt"
MOVE  "C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\System software" C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\desktop\System software 2"
ECHO Complete
PAUSE
```

You have

1. created a directory
2. but then created a file outside of this directory
3. moved the directory you have created to a directory named exactly the same as the file you have created in step 2.

Comment: thanks very much, your input helped a lot, thanks again.

Comment: there is also a systemvariable `%USERPROFILE%`. More flexible than hardcoding the username: `md "%userprofile%\Desktop\System Software"` etc.